# Retrieving a list of all failed Glue jobs via CLI

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-glue

Is there a way to retrieve a list of all failed Glue jobs within a certain time period (e.g. last 24 h) via AWS CLI/SDK? Essentially, I am looking for a programmatic way to get the information contained in AWS Glue > Monitoring.

Internally the web page gets it by making a request to:
`https://gluestudio-service.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/queryRuns?DateRangeColumnName=startedOn&MaxDateRange=2024-03-28%2021%3A59%3A59.999000&MaxResults=200&MinDateRange=2024-03-27%2022%3A00%3A00.000000&QueryString=jobRunStatus%3AFAILED&SortColumnName=startedOn&SortOrder=desc`

but this doesn't seem to be a public API.